# DateTime.now or DateTime.UTC please advise

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Hi I'm developing a windows form application(C#) which will be used on various geographical locations, and  requires 2 parameters , business from hour and business to hour. This looks like

```
business from hr: 08:00
business to hr: 17:00
```

I need to do validation against these two times to check whether the current local hour is within business hours or not. To get the local current hour  which time should I be referencing? Is it `DateTime.Now` or `Datetime.UtcNow`? Please advise.

Comment: As the name says, dateTime.UTC is the UTC time and NOT the local time (except local time is in fact UTC).

Comment: It should depend, i.e. will the same store be used by someone in another timezone? if so, you should use UTC time but store the timezone too so as to help the other timezone person use the data accurately through convertions, otherwise you can use localtime

Comment: You  need to do the business hour range validation on server side (Database) or the client side (i.e. in the windows form application iteself)?

Comment: It all depends really, a lot of places I've worked there is a general agreement on a timezone (UTC) but then you need to work on the time difference.  If you always want local then use DateTime.Now.  I feel this question will open up a can of worms that can't be answered easily.

Comment: It good practice to store Datetime in UTC together with the timezone especially in web applications, since UTC is objective while localtime is subjective.

Comment: Thanks for response. I am developing outlook addin and I need to do client side validation. Server will be the local outlook -ms server , from where I need to get the local time. My confusion is , If you travel geographically across, should validate with local business hrs ,

Answer (score 0):

In a WinForms app, local time is `DateTime.Now`.

See [MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).